# One WCF Service Multiple Namespaces?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working with WCF and I have am looking to develop an API with multiple endpoints and namespaces. I have the multiple endpoints down, it's just about how to 'whitelabel' the namespace to the particular customer.

For example, if Customer 1 connects I want the XML service definition to look something like this:

```
<p:SomeRequest xmlns:p="http://customer1.co.uk/Info-GetInfo-v1-0" xmlns:padsl="http://customer1.co.uk/GetInfo-Blah-v1.0" xmlns:a="http://customer1.co.uk/foo-InfoGetter-v1-0">
```

If customer 2 connects, I want it to be like this:

```
<p:SomeRequest xmlns:p="http://customer2.co.uk/Info-GetInfo-v1-0" xmlns:padsl="http://customer2.co.uk/GetInfo-Blah-v1.0" xmlns:a="http://customer2.co.uk/foo-InfoGetter-v1-0">
```

I've had a google, but can't work out how to achieve this, any constructive advice is welcome.

## Code Snippet

```
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace = "http://mydomain.co.uk")]
public class GetInfoService : IGetInfoService
{
    private void SomeRequest(object request)
    {
        if (request != null)
        {
            // Do Something
        }
    }
}
```

Many Thanks,
Dan

Comment: You can define the namespace in endpoint configuration itself. Use bindingnamespace attribute todo so.

Comment: Dan, just to clarify, you have one service, but as you want to serve different clients, you want each one has its own namespace, but for the same service, is it correct?

Comment: @RicardoPontual - That's correct.

Comment: Each service interface (ServiceContract) and service class (ServiceBehavior) allow one namespace. You can configure multiples endpoints to the same contract in your Web.config, and assign each one with a different namespace with bindingNamespace tag (system.serviceModel - services - service -endpoint)